# why it always giving call integer parameter method not short parameter method

Tags: java, overloading

This is my code:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Test().method1(5);
    }
    public void method1(int b) { // integer method
        System.out.println("integer ");
    }
    public void method1(short a) { // short method
        System.out.println("short");
    }
}
```

I am running this class, and it gives me result of `integer`. Why it is not giving `short`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the literal `5` is by default understood as an `int`. If you want to call the `method1(short a)` method, you need to explicitly do a cast:

```
new Test().method1((short) 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The literal `5` has type `int`, that's why the method that expects an `int` is called.

`new Test().method1((short)5)` would call the method that expects a `short`.

Comment: So just curious, there's no way to convert a user input to numeric data type and if it fits in short, automatically to invoke the short method, etc.. ?

Comment: @RoyalBg nope. That would be a bad idea, with no redeeming positive sides that I can see. It'll almost certainly operate more slowly than using an `int` (see my answer to this question).

Comment: @RoyalBg Obviously you could do the check yourself, and then cast to the smallest type that will fit.

Comment: @RoyalBg When you use a method to convert user data to numeric type, you are choosing the type - Short.parseShort(str) would return a `short` (or throw an exception). Intger.parseInt(str) would return an `int`. The compiler chooses which overloaded method to call based on the type of the variable at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Default type of Java integer literals is int thats why integer method is getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply `type conversion` because you are willing to call a function which receives short.

try calling  with:`(short)5`

Answer (score 0):

It's because, as noted in the other answers, a `5` on its own denotes an `int`. You can denote a `long` by appending an `L`, so `5L` would be treated as a `long`. If you want a `byte` or a `short` then you have to cast explicitly.

It may be that you have a good reason for wanting a method that takes a `short`, but please bear in mind that this is quite rare. Certainly you would not want to be doing this for performance reasons. Java uses a 32-bit `int` by default because pretty much every processor out there can work natively with 32-bit integers. You will *probably* find that a `short` will operate *more slowly* than an `int`.

(Of course, if you're doing specifically 16-bit arithmetic, then you might still need to use a `short`.)